# How to add an ID to an image using only javascript

Tags: javascript, image

Basically I'm trying to give my image an id... but I'm not sure if this is possible without using HTML... if you're confused just look at my code

```
function add_conner_6th() {
    var src = "src";
    show_image("src", 300,415, "Conner 6th");
}

function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
    var img = document.createElement("src");
    img.src = src;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.alt = alt;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

I've tried adding img.id = "name" but it just doesn't work. I'M DESPERATE

Comment: Did you try `img.id="name";` with the semicolon?

Comment: Try creating an image, not a `src` element ?

Comment: @TJonS yes. But when the image appears, I use document.getElementById and then it will not find the image by that it... yet when I created an image simply in html and used the same id, it deleted THAT image

Comment: @user3367007 try `img` instead of `src` for the element you are creating. Let me know if that one works.

Comment: @TJonS nope. I feel like I've found a solution... could I possibly eliminate all of the complications and use a document.display?

Comment: @user3367007 That should be fine. What are you using this for?

Comment: @user3367007 do you mean `.display="block";` or the like?

Answer (score 2):

`img.id = "name"` should work, but I believe the issue is that you have `createElement("src")`. That should be `createElement("img")`, for example:

```
function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
    var img =
        document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.alt = alt;
    img.id = "name";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/DDfhQ/)